# Woocommerce - Edit widget_shopping_cart_content

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to change the view of the dropdown mini menu in woocommerce. 
Now, when you open the mini cart, you have list of product's then you have the buttons. 
We want make it oposit. Buttons then list of products.

I search myself, but i cant work it out.  Can anybody help me?

[Before and after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8InR.jpg)

Comment: Do you have the URL please to check look ?

Comment: To do this safely, Its better to create a child theme and edit your mini cart's files in the theme. Of course other solutions are also possible if you post the site URL

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to bring most important thing ;) www.deepcut.pl